# How do you close a JFrame dialog box?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When I put in the code below I get the error: "local variable classWindow is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final."

```
classWindow.dispose();
```

I did put:

```
private final void classWindow
```

and I still get the error.

```
private final void classWindow() {
  // Create the frame
  JFrame classWindow = new JFrame("Pick A Class");

  // Set the size of the frame
  classWindow.setSize(230, 150);

  // Specify an action for the close button.
  setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  // Add a layout manager to the content pane.
  setLayout(new GridLayout());

  JButton warriorButton = new JButton("Warrior");   

  warriorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        userClass = "Warrior";
        classWindow.dispose();
        }});

  classWindow.add(warriorButton, BorderLayout.WEST);

  classWindow.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
  classWindow.setVisible(true);
}
```

Yes, I did look it up and that's why I tried the 'final' thing and it doesn't seem to work on my code for some weird reason.  I'm sure it is a very simple fix.

Comment: _JFrame dialog box_ sounds weird, why not a `JDialog`? :)

Comment: I heartily second @BackSlash's recommendation -- use a JDialog for dialog windows, not a JFrame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ultimate reason is confusing way to name variables and methods. The error is referring to the variable, which need to be final:

```
final JFrame classWindow = new JFrame("Pick A Class");
```

I would seriously recommend also picking a different name for it.

Comment: @Xearta: if kiheru's answer solved your problem, then kindly accept his answer by clicking on the large check mark to the left of his answer. But again I must re-iterate that you should use a JDialog here, not a JFrame.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Sorry, I had to wait 15 minutes. Kind of lame.

Comment: @Xearta: no, not lame. This will change as you gain rep.